# What is the average google maps geocoder response time?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

What is the average Geocoder response time (i.e. from the time you make the request till the time you get the response back)?

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour   I think that your question is very subjective based on how many points you are attempting to geocode, etc. Are you currently experiencing lag time or receiving timeout errors?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Python requests module to get average request times.  I'll say from my experiences it is very fast.  The [request response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) object has an `elapsed` property that tells how long the request took.

Here's a quick sample.  **I tested against 10 NFL stadiums and the average response time was `0.0374s`**:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib

GOOGLE = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

def google_getCoordinates(query, from_sensor=False, googleGeocodeUrl=GOOGLE):
    """use google geocoder to get coordinates from adddress

    query -- address to geocode
    """
    query = query.encode('utf-8')
    params = {
        'address': query,
        'sensor': "true" if from_sensor else "false"
    }

    response = requests.get(googleGeocodeUrl + urllib.urlencode(params))
    json_response = response.json()

    if json_response['results']:
        location = json_response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
        latitude, longitude = location['lat'], location['lng']
    else:
        latitude, longitude = None, None
        print query, "<no results>"
    return ((longitude, latitude), response)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    nfl_stadiums = ['11001 OWINGS MILLS ROAD, OWINGS MILLS, MD 21117',
                    '1 BILLS DRIVE, ORCHARD PARK, NY 14127',
                    '1 PAUL BROWN STADIUM, CINCINNATI, OH 45202',
                    '76 LOU GROZA BLVD.,BEREA, OH 44017',
                    '13655 BRONCOS PARKWAY, ENGLEWOOD, CO 80112',
                    '1 RELIANT PARK, HOUSTON, TX 77054',
                    '7001 W. 56TH STREET, INDIANAPOLIS, IN 46254',
                    '1 STADIUM PLACE, JACKSONVILLE, FL 32202',
                    '1 ARROWHEAD DRIVE, KANSAS CITY, MO 64129',
                    '500 SW 30TH STREET, DAVIE, FL 33314']

    # get request times
    coords, response = [], []
    for stadium in nfl_stadiums:
        c, r = google_getCoordinates(stadium)
        coords.append(c)
        response.append(r.elapsed.total_seconds())

    # find average response time
    average = float(sum(response) / len(response))
    print average
```

You can also use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to view stats on web requests.

Comment: Thanks crmackey. I am assuming this time doesn't include UI rendering does it?

Comment: Correct, that is just strictly HTTP request time.